# Caching - Fix browsers locally caching pages

Tags: caching, varnish

I'm a bit unsure what it happening here but ill try to explain what is happening and maybe write a better question once i figured out what i'm actually asking.

I have just installed Varnish which seems awesome for my request times. It is a Magneto 2 store which I have followed the default configuration within dev docs for varnish.

**My Issue**

Currently my issue is that the browser seems to be caching the page until i click refresh. I believe i am successfully flushing / purging the cache with magento / varnish. As when using Curl to request the page i can see a new page is generated each time i flush cache and just serves cached page if i don't.

Within chrome and firefox however on my client pc however the whole page markup seems to be cached (when clicking a link to page or pasting url in browser) until clicking refresh which seems to reload the real page. When deploying new static files etc as the old resources are still in the cached markup and the new location for resources is signed e.g. version1234/styles.css and not matching the markup i get CSS less pages until client clicks refresh and loads the actual markup from server?

How can i setup caching so that this does not happen?

> **Curl -IL result of URL:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Nov 2017 12:08:32 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Expires: Sun, 26 Nov 2017 15:55:17 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=186400, public, s-maxage=186400
Pragma: cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=186400, public, s-maxage=186400
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT
Grace: none
age: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Please post the output of ```curl -IL your-url```

Comment: @DanielV. added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser caching takes please because of these headers being sent:

```
Expires: Sun, 26 Nov 2017 15:55:17 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=186400, public, s-maxage=186400
```

You should adjust your server configuration so that those are not sent for PHP. Most likely you have a configuration block in nginx or .htaccess that applies to the whole website, as opposed to just static files.

Comment: Ok i cant find where this is actually set cant see it in magento or varnish however. Can i just override with varnish like so: https://serverfault.com/questions/54219/configuring-varnish-to-rewrite-expires-cache-control-headers-for-client-side-cac

Comment: set resp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=0, public, s-maxage=0";
unset resp.http.Expires;

Comment: This fixed the headers atleast page still seems quick. Is this something you would recommend or should i find the source so i can still control expires with .htaccess

Comment: Does this one matter also: X-Magento-Cache-Control: max-age=186400, public, s-maxage=186400?

Comment: The ```X-Magento-Cache-Control``` is just for debugging purpose, it does not apply anywhere. It is best to hunt down where you have the problematic headers originate from. It can be anything including .htaccess / nginx configuration / Magento plugin.

Comment: I will try just checked the htaccess will look so,e more tho does seem to have foxed my issue tho so thank